# How can I flag all uses of a default parameter at compile time

Tags: c++

I'd like to find all places where a second default parameter for a constructor is used.  The signature looks something like this:

```
enum Name {
    NONE = 0,
    BOB,
    LARRY
};

MyClass(const std::string& p1, int id = 0, name = NONE)
  : p1_(p1), id_(id), name_(name)
{ }
```

I'm interested in finding all places where the default value of name is used. That is, all call sites where no value is explicitly provided for name. I'm not concerned about where NONE is explicitly provided, only where name is not provided in the constructor.

This strikes me as something that should be discoverable at compile time and that, therefore, I can use the compiler to alert me to.

My initial thought was to remove NONE as a default, compile, and look through the warnings. But then I realized that the parameter before it, id, has a default value so removing the default `= NONE` for name will not compile because you can't have parameters without defaults after parameters that do.

My second attempt was to add a new Name enumerated value called DEFAULT_WAS_USED, set that as the default, and compile with a static_assert:

```
enum Name {
    NONE = 0,
    BOB,
    LARRY,
    DEFAULT_WAS_USED
};

MyClass(const std::string& p1, int id = 0, name = DEFAULT_WAS_USED)
  : p1_(p1), id_(id), name_(name)
{
    static_assert(name_ != DEFAULT_WAS_USED, "default name was used");
}
```

However, while the use of name as DEFAULT_WAS_USED would strictly be known at compile time since I know that value isn't used anywhere in the code and would only be used as a default parameter, the compiler doesn't know that's the case and fails to compile this.

Is there a clever way for me to use the compiler or linker to find all places in the code where the default parameter is used?

I'm using gcc 4.8.

Comment: I would remove the defaults from both `id` and `name` and then look through the compiler errors that result.  I reckon that's the best you can do.

Comment: Have you tried `grep`? Just in case...

Comment: @cdonat Falls apart a bit with braced-init-lists and emplace_back and such. The type name is not always given at the point of construction, so what do you grep for? Okay the emplace_back example is not good

Comment: If you want to break compilation, why not just remove the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to catch places where `name`'s default is used, it doesn't really matter that `id` has a default too: nobody's going to be using it unless they also used `name`'s default, which is a case you want to catch anyway.

So just strip both defaults and watch the flames fly.

But there's no magic flag or switch to precisely/automatically do specifically what you're asking, no.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is add a couple deleted constructors and get rid of the default parameters in the "main" constructor.

```
struct MyClass
{
    MyClass(const std::string& p1) = delete;
    MyClass(const std::string& p1, int id)  = delete;
    MyClass(const std::string& p1, int id, Name name) : p1_(p1), id_(id), name_(name) {}
    std::string p1_;
    int id_;
    Name name_;
};
```

will error out for

```
MyClass{"foo"};
MyClass{"foo", 10};
```

but will not be an error for

```
MyClass{"foo", 42, BOB};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might create overload:

```
MyClass(const std::string& p1, int id, Name name)
  : p1_(p1), id_(id), name_(name)
{}

MyClass(const std::string& p1, int id = 0) = delete; // Name no provided explicitly
```